# how to use controls of 1 from in another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm using a main form and edit form, and i want to use the edit form text boxes in the main form, how can i do it?

**edit**

can't use user controls.

Comment: @Why can't you use user controls?

Comment: because it said so in the homework defenitions

Comment: By "use the edit form text boxes", do you mean you want to access the values of the text boxes that are on the edit form from the main form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be create properties that expose the text fields. Call your edit form, then read the properties back.

```
public class MainForm
{
  private void OnEditClick()
  {
    EditForm editForm = new EditForm();
    DialogResult result = editForm.ShowDialog(this);
    //check the result for ok/cancel etc if your using them.
    whatever = editForm.TextBox1;
    whatever2 = editForm.TextBox2;
}

public class EditForm
{
  public string TextBox1 { get { return textBox1.Text;} }
  public string TextBox2 { get { return textBox2.Text;} }
  // etc
}
```

You could expose the whole control, but if all you care about is the contents of the text boxes, creating properties to expose just those is cleaner.

Comment: I think a better method would be to have a global public class which stores the data, and then access the properties from that global class. Of course you could also create a DataSource, and set the binding of the forms to that datasource and then hook into events in the datasource.

Comment: Were it a serious program, I probably would build an object to represent the data and retrieve that.But since it's tagged as homework, the added complexity has little benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be live? If not, add a property on the edit form and store the value (like an OpenFileDialog does when retrieving the .Filename). After it's closed, retrieve back the property and place it in the main form.

If it does need to be live, you probably need to use events (implement something close to INotifyPropertyChanged in Silverlight) then have the mainform attach to the edit form's events and update the controls as necessary (remember to check if InvokeRequired!)